# search for column names in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

Because there are many tables with many columns, I need a query to search for column names in a specific table.

example:

```
select column_name from table where column_name like '%ID%'
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For Oracle

```
select COLUMN_NAME from ALL_TAB_COLUMNS 
  where TABLE_NAME='mytable' and COLUMN_NAME like '%ID%';
```

Comment: thanks this worked for me, one note is to use all uppercase letters in Oracle. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are on an Oracle database, try this:

```
select column_name
from user_tab_columns
where table_name = 'MY_TABLE' and column_name like '%ID%';
```

If the table is in a different schema, you can use:

```
select column_name
from all_tab_columns
where owner = 'TABLE_OWNER' and table_name = 'MY_TABLE' and column_name like '%ID%';
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM ALL_TAB_COLUMNS 
WHERE COLUMN_NAME LIKE '%ID%' 
AND owner = 'database_name' AND table_name = 'MY_TABLE';
```